# Plot tree with graph.tree function from igraph

Tags: r, igraph

In the docs of igraph package there is an example

```
igraph.options(plot.layout=layout.reingold.tilford)
plot(graph.tree(20, 2))
```

the output should represent data as a tree. But what I get is

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You apparently need to specify the root:

```
library(igraph)
g <- graph.tree(20, 2)
plot(g, layout = layout.reingold.tilford(g, root=1))
```

[image: tree]

Comment: That was just trial and error: I checked `?layout.reingold.tilford` and changed the arguments until it worked. It could be a bug, because the default value for the root is supposed to be 1.

Comment: How can I do full binary trees (every vertex has exactly two children)?

Comment: Just provide a full binary tree as input: `g <- graph.tree(2^5-1, 2)`.