# Plotting a tree in R given existing values

Tags: r, tree

Let's say I have an existing numeric vector `num <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)` and I need to visualize it in the simplest way possible (every node have two children) -- like this (sorry, I'm definitely not an artist):

[image: sample tree]

Is it possible with R?

Comment: Maybe start [searching in SO](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=relevance&q=[r]%20tree%20diagram)

Comment: `num` caries no information on how the nodes are related. If you need only one or a few graphs, try [yEd graph editor](https://www.yworks.com/en/products/yfiles/yed/).

Comment: @RomanLuštrik Having in mind that it's a simplest possible tree (every node have two children), wouldn't their position be enough?

Comment: Yes, but that is an assumption that one needs to make. :)

Comment: @RomanLuštrik, And if we make that assumption (the original post edited, sorry I wasn't clear), is it possibile then? :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Plot tree with graph.tree function from igraph](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18270370/plot-tree-with-graph-tree-function-from-igraph)

Comment: it's a duplicate and the question has already bin nicely answered.

Comment: Just came across this widget, you might want to give it a go. http://www.htmlwidgets.org/showcase_diagrammer.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
num <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)
library(igraph)
library(psych)
g <- graph.edgelist(matrix(c(rep(seq_len((length(num)-1) / 2), each = 2), num[-1]), ncol = 2))
plot(g, layout = factor.rotate(layout.reingold.tilford(g), angle = -90), ylim = c(1, -1))
```

[image]