# How to plot a tree using network package in R

Tags: r

I am using `network` package in R to plot a small graph. I use the following commands.

```
    library("network")
    g<-network.initialize(6)
    add.edge(g,1,2)
    add.edge(g,1,3)
    add.edge(g,1,4)
    add.edge(g,3,6)
    add.edge(g,4,5)
    plot(g,label=network.vertex.names(g))
```

I get the graph as shown in the picture. [sample graph from network package in r](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rhc7i.png)

I want it to look more like a tree. 
node 1 in first layer
nodes 2,3,4 in second layer
nodes 5,6 in third layer.How to do that?

Comment: then you should replace the `1` by `2` because in your code it states that `1` is connected to 3 points. It thus can't be at the bottom of the "tree"

Comment: try the `igraph` package. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18270370/plot-tree-with-graph-tree-function-from-igraph

Answer (score 0):

```
plot(g,label=network.vertex.names(g), interactive=T)
```

using "interactive=T", you can manually change the shape of the network and determine the position of each node.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. :-)